# Expand $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ into a series so that you can calculate $\sqrt{0.9999999995}$ with a precision of 10 digits

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So, I have to expand $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ into a series with terms $(x-1)$ in it and then using that series I have to find how many of the serie's terms I have to use so I can calculate $\sqrt{0.9999999995}$ with a precision of 10 digits.

I have solved the first part, though I am stuck in the second one.

Let, $y=x-1$. Then:
$$\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}=(y+1)^{1/2}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{{1/2}\choose n}*y^n=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{{1/2}\choose n}*(x-1)^n$$

This occured from the Taylor's expansion in $f(x)=(y+1)^{1/2}$.

Now, I can't figure out what the next step should be. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Expand a few terms of the $y$ series.

Comment: Note that $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}{{1/2}\choose n}*(x-1)^n \approx \sum^k_{n=0}{{1/2}\choose n}*(x-1)^n$$Now you just have to figure out which $k$ is large enough to give the desired precision.

Comment: @Arthur So, I just check values for k?

Comment: Do you know what Taylor's theorem really says? Because it doesn't only say that a finite Taylor series approximates a given function. It also says something about how big the error may at most be. Find the $k$ that makes that error term small enough, and you have found the $k$ that makes $\sum^k_{n=0}{{1/2}\choose n}*(x-1)^n$ close enough to $\sqrt{x}$, for $x = 0.9999999995$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $0.9999999995=1-5\cdot 10^{-10}=1+y$. The Maclaurin series with [Lagrange's remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) is
$$
\sqrt{0.9999999995}=(1+y)^{1/2}=1+\frac12 y-\frac18(1+\theta y)^{-3/2}y^2,\quad 0\le \theta\le 1.
$$
Estimate
$$
\left|-\frac18(1+\theta y)^{-3/2}y^2\right|\le\frac18\frac{25\cdot 10^{-20}}{(1-5\cdot 10^{-10})^{3/2}}\le\frac18\frac{25\cdot 10^{-20}}{(1-\frac34)^{3/2}}=25\cdot 10^{-20} 
$$
to see that it is small enough, then approximate 
$$
\sqrt{0.9999999995}\approx 1-\frac5210^{-10}
$$
and take $10$ digits.

Comment: So, you are saying that taking $two$ terms from the Taylor's series is enough so the error would be small enough?

Comment: @George.K Yes, for $10$ digits it is enough because $y$ has order $10^{-10}$, so already $y^2$ is negligible compared to first $10$ digits.